# Why does GCC not assign the static variable when it is initialized to 0

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, static

I initialize a static variable to 0, but when I see the assembly code, I find that only memory is allocated to the variable. The value is not assigned
And when I initialize the static variable to other numbers, I can find that the memory is assigned a value.
I guess whether GCC thinks the memory should be initialized to 0 by OS before we use the memory.

The GCC option I use is "gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -c -o"

When I initialize the static variable to 0, the c code and the assembly code:

```c
static int temp_front=0;
```

```
.local  temp_front.1909
.comm   temp_front.1909,4,4
```

When I initialize it to other numbers, the code is:

```c
static int temp_front=1;
```

```
    .align 4
    .type   temp_front.1909, @object
    .size   temp_front.1909, 4
temp_front.1909:
    .long   1
```

Comment: Global variables are by default initialized to zero. There is nothing for the compiler to do.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If nobody does it, nothing gets done. At best, your "explanation" is devoid of information.

Comment: @Deduplicator, OK: uninitialzed global variables are placed in the .BSS segment. The loader allocates memory for the .BSS segment and initializes it to zero.

Comment: loader or boostrap zeros .bss.  this question is clearly demonstrating .data vs .bss though, that is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL:DR: GCC knows the BSS is guaranteed to be zero-initialized on the platform it's targeting so it puts zero-initialized static data there.

## Big picture

The program loader of most modern operating systems gets two different sizes for each part of the program, like the data part. The first size it gets is the size of data stored in the executable file (like a [PE/COFF `.EXE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) file on Windows or an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable on Linux), while the second size is the size of the data part in memory while the program is running.

If the data size for the running program is bigger than the amount of data stored in the executable file, the remaining part of the data section is filled with bytes containing zero. In your program, the `.comm` line tells the linker to reserve 4 bytes without initializing them, so that the OS zero-initializes them on start.

## What does gcc do?

`gcc` (or any other C compiler) allocates zero-initialized variables with static storage duration in the `.bss` section. Everything allocated in that section will be zero-initialized on program startup. For allocation, it uses the `comm` directive, and it just specifies the size (4 bytes).

You can see the size of the main section types (code, data, bss) using the size command. If you initialize the variable with one, it is included in a `data` section, and occupies 4 bytes there. If you initialize it with zero (or not at all), it is instead allocated in the .bss section.

## What does ld do?

ld merges all data-type section of all object files (even those from static libraries) into one data section, followed by all `.bss`-type sections. The executable output contains a simplified view for the operating system's program loader.  For ELF files, this is the "[program header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Program_header)". You can take a look at it using `objdump -p` for any format, or `readelf` for ELF files.

The program headers contain of entries of different type. Among them are a couple of entries with the type `PT_LOAD` describing the "segments" to be loaded by the operating system. One of these PT_LOAD entries is for the data area (where the `.data` section is linked).  It contains an entry called `p_filesz` that specifies how many bytes for initialized variables are provided in the ELF file, and an entry called `p_memsz` telling the loader how much space in the address space should be reserved. The details on which sections get merged into what PT_LOAD entries differ between linkers and depend on command line options, but generally you will find a PT_LOAD entry that describes a region that is both readable and writeable, but not executable, and has a `p_filesz` value that is smaller than the `p_memsz` entry (potentially zero if there's only a `.bss`, no `.data` section). `p_filesz` is the size of all read+write data sections, whereas `p_memsz` is bigger to also provide space for zero-initialized variables.

The amount `p_memsz` exceeds `p_filesz` is the sum of all `.bss` sections linked into the executable. (The values might be off a bit due to alignment to pages or disk blocks)

See chapter 5 in [the System V ABI specification](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf), especially pages 5-2 and 5-3 for a description of the program header entries.

## What does the operating system do?

The Linux kernel (or another ELF-compliant kernel) iterates over all entries in the program header. For each entry containing the type `PT_LOAD` it allocates virtual address space. It associates the beginning of that address space with the corresponding region in the executable file, and if the space is writeable, it enables copy-on-write.

If `p_memsz` exceeds `p_filesz`, the kernel arranges the remaining address space to be completely zeroed out. So the variable that got allocated in the `.bss` section by gcc ends up in the "tail" of the read-write PT_LOAD entry in the ELF file, and the kernel provides the zero.

Any whole pages that have no backing data can start out copy-on-write mapped to a shared physical page of zeros.

Comment: Well explained. And that is the reason you want all-bits-zero as the correct initialization-value if you can trivially arrange it. Even for non-static objects zeroing is generally cheaper.

Comment: I find this a confusing answer: "If the data size for the running program is bigger than the amount of data stored in the executable file." And note that the program is not yet running. It is being loaded. Please see my new comment with the question, which is the only correct explanation.

Comment: Can you supply any documentation or other reference for the statement that the loader gets a total size and a size of the data stored in the executable file and fills in the difference with zeros? My understanding is that an executable file generally contains descriptions of a number of segments, not often just two (read-only executable code, read-only data, writeable data, data to be initialized to zero, and possibly additional segments of those types and others). Then the loader processes each segment. It provides zeros not to fill in a gap but because there is an explicit segment of zeros.

Comment: (The explicit segment of zeros is not represented with literal zeros in the executable file but with a segment descriptor that says it is a segment initialized to zero and stating its length.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil While the description is simplified, it's more or less what happens. Each section (PECOFF) or program segment (ELF) in the executable has a size on disk and a size in memory. If the later size is bigger than the former then the section/segment in memory is padded with zeros.  http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.pheader.html#segment_contents "Normally, these uninitialized data reside at the end of the segment, thereby making p_memsz larger than p_filesz in the associated program header element."

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your description is true for the sections used for linking, i.e. the section headers in the ELF file. My description is true for the loading process when you run the program, i.e. the program headers in the ELF file. I expanded my answer to talk about both.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I had thought that GNU Binutils `ld` did normally create separate ELF segments to link `.data` and `.bss` into, but that turns out not to be the case at least these days.  I updated this answer with links to the ELF and PE/COFF wikipedia pages.  The ELF page includes details of how program headers work.  I did some local testing with a trivial NASM `.asm` file with a .data and .bss, linking that into a static "executable" with no `.text` section (and no entry point) gave me a single ELF segment, even with "uneven" sizes of data declared / reserved in .bss and .data.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why** does GCC not assign ...

Most modern OSs will automatically zero-initialize the BSS section.

Using such an OS an "uninitialized" variable is identical to a variable that is initialized to zero.

However, there is one difference: The data of uninitialized variables are not stored in the resulting object and executable files; the data of initialized variables is.

This means that "real" zero-initialized variables may lead to a larger file size compared to uninitialized variables.

For this reason the compiler prefers using "uninitialized" variables if variables are really zero-initialized.

> The GCC option I use is ...

Of course there are also operating systems which do **not** automatically initialize "uninitialized" memory to zero.

As far as I remember Windows 95 is an example for this.

If you want to compile for such an operating system, you may use the GCC command line option `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss`. This command line option forces GCC to "really" zero-initialize variables that are zero-initialized.

I just compiled your code with that command line option; the output looks like this:

```
    .data
    .align 4
    .type     temp_front, @object
    .size     temp_front, 4
 temp_front:
    .zero  4
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no point even in Windows 95 to make zero-initialisation in code of every compiled module. May be the Win95 program loader (or even MS-DOS) does not initialize the bss section, but the "ctr0" init module (linked in every comppiled C/C++ program, and that will finally call main() or the DllEntry point, can do that directly in a fast operation for the whole BSS section, whose size is already on the program header and that can also be determined in a static preinitialized variable whose value is computed by the linker, and there's no need to change the way each module is compiled with gcc.

However there are more difficulties about automatic variables (local variables allocated on the stack): the compiler does not know if the variable will be initialized if its first use is by reference in a call parameter (to a non-inlined function, which may be in another module compiled separately or linked from an external library or DLL), supposed to fill it.

GCC only knows when the variable is explicitly assigned in the function itself, but if it gets used by reference only, GCC can now fircibly preinitialize it to zero to prevent it to keep a sensitive value left on the stack. In that case this adds some zero-fill code in the compiled function preamble for these local variables, and this helps prevent some data leaks (generally such leak is unlikely when the varaible is a simple type, but when it is a whole structure, many fields may be left in random state by the subcall.

C11 indicates that such code assuming initialization of auto variables has "undefined" behavior. But GCC will help close the security risk: this is allowed by C11 because this forced zeroing is better to leaving random value and both behaviors are conforming to the "undefined" behavior: zero is as well acceptable as a randomly leaked value.

Some secure functions also avoid leaving senstive data when returning, they explicitly clear the variables they no longer need to avoid expose them after these function return (and notably when they return from a privilege code to an unprivileged one): this is a good practice, but it is independant of the forced initilization of auto variables used by references in subcalls before they were initialized. And GCC is smart enough to not forcibly initialize these auto varaibles when there's explicit code that assign them an explicit value. So the impact is minimal. This feature may be disabled in GCC for those apps that want microoptimizations in terms of performance, but in both cases this does not add to the BSS size, and the image size just grows by only <0.1% for the Linux kernel only because of the few bytes of code compiled in a few functions that benefit of this security fix.

And this has no effect on "uninitialized" static variables, that GCC puts in the BSS section, cleared by the program loader of the OS, or by the small program's crt0 init module.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you mention the GCC options you're talking about, so people can look them up in the GCC manual or try them on https://godbolt.org/ to see what actual difference they make.